# Widget with unique before & after code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a widget that doesn't use the regular before and after code that's specified by the sidebar.

Essentially I have a button that I want to be able to place in my sidebars but if it's surrounded by the usual border and padding that the other widgets use it looks all wrong.

Is there a way to have a widget that doesn't follow the rules of the sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around this. The widgets are created with a unique ID. You can use this to style the particular widget any way you want.